# Passing objects of a class in the form of an ArrayList when instantiating another class

Tags: java

I have a graph class which requires an ArrayList of Vertex to instantiate, but how do I get objects of Vertex from the object bench in BlueJ to be passed in ArrayList form in the parameter window?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Vs8.png)

Comment: do you have some code you tried to write to show us?

Comment: your choice of IDE is not relevant. by passing them as parameters, normally.

Comment: @Coreggon public Graph(ArrayList<Vertex> vertices, ArrayList<Edge> edges) is my graph constructor, but it is more of a question about blueJ, when the create object window comes up for graph, how would I get the Vertex objects on the object bench into the form of an array list to pass successfully, as it doesn't work in this format {vertex1, vertex2 etc.} .

Comment: well, I assume you have a main method where you create a `new Graph`, so there you just create `List list = new List` and when you create  `Vertex vertex = new Vertex` then you call `list.add(vertex)` and pass the `list` as argument to the `Graph`